# apache 2.4 for windows install/run as a service, available for all users

Tags: apache

I have downloaded Apache 2.4 for windows, as its zip file I extracted ansd started using. however I need to "install/run as a service, available for all users"

need help to do same.
Thanks  in advance.

Comment: @Filburt  ... its not just about running as services only, I'm looking for Running as a service for ALL USERS. there is diff. find same in 10s then comment again.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the .zip file to somewhere like `C:\Apache24`. Next navigate to `C:\Apache24\bin` in command prompt.

Then type:

```
httpd -k install
```

You can then start Apache as a service by typing:

```
httpd -k start
```

You will also be able to control Apache via Services in Administrative tools after restart.

For all users you can install the service using the `.msi` file. You need to [compile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/win_compiling.html) (see 'Command Line Build') the source in the `.zip` you downloaded to produce this file.

Alternatively if you obtain a pre-built `.msi` you can install from there as well.

Once it's compiled if you install Apache via the installer and select `All Users` when prompted for who to install for it will install the service for all users.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the method you have mentioned will not install it as service for all users. I need to install one plugin/software which will detect service only when its installed for All Users.

Comment: @rohitrk89 I've updated my answer. Should hopefully be what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks I'm trying to do 'Command Line Build' facing issues. wil update once done.. thanks again...

Comment: stucked at 

The system cannot find the path specified.
ARCH        = Win32 Release
APR_PATH    = ..\apr
API_PATH    = ..\apr-iconv  (apr-iconv)
APU_PATH    = ..\apr-util  (apr-util)
PREFIX      = ..\apr-dist  (install path)
DBD_LIST    =
DBM_LIST    =
CRYPTO_LIST =
Please check out or download and unpack the Apache Portability Runtime
sources (apr, apr-iconv and apr-util) under a single parent dir,
or provide APR_PATH, API_PATH and APU_PATH (all relative to each other,
or all absolute paths).
Apache cannot build without these libraries!

Makefile.win(157) : fatal error U1050: Need apr and apr

Comment: If you're having trouble compiling you should be able to find the `.msi` installer you need [from here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/).

Comment: msi files are till only version 2.2.x and I'm looking for 2.4.x , searched for that too, couldn't get that and couldn't even compile.

Comment: it wil be great help if you have and can provide me msi for 2.4.